# Is it normal for authenticated users to be need to sign back in after web.config edit?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I noticed on a asp.net mvc web application after a web.config edit a signed in user needed to sign back in.   I'm aware any web.config changes cause an app pool cycle and there is a few seconds of down time.  I also know that session state is killed but we're not using it for persistent variable storage.

But I'm curious why would the user need to sign back in?  Is session state tied to authentication?  The Forms authentication ticket is still valid.  Any ideas?

```
 var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,
            user.Email,
            now,
            tokenExpire,
            false,
            user.Email,
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

        var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Expires = tokenExpire,
                Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
                Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
            };
```

Comment: I think Session is abandoned abruptly.

Comment: @Nanosoft thanks, I updated the question.  So does that mean if session is killed their auth cookie expires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it normal for authenticated users to be need to sign back in after
>   web.config edit?

No. But, there's an indirect effect to the authentication ticket to be invalidated.

Firstly, Web.config edit triggers the app pool to be recycled, which indirectly cause the [machineKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to be auto generated if not [set as static in your Web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations)

The keys in machineKey are used in `FormsAuthentication.Encrypt()` and `FormsAuthentication.Decrypt()` methods. Since machineKey has new values after the app pool recycle your FormsAuthentication.Decrypt() will not give you the correct ticket. Hence the user is not authenticated and will be redirected to the login page.

So, my suggestion is to set static machineKeys instead of auto generated keys. You could add a section in your Web.config as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations).

Hope this answered your question.

Comment: Even if you can fix the `machineKey`, an app pool restart will clear in-proc session state. If your application depends on session state, then be prepared to have session variables removed.

Comment: Yes, correct. If you are not handling null values (wherever you are using session variables) the authenticated users will see errors